# React-native-image-progress doesn't show progress

Tags: react-native

I'm using [react-native-image-progress](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-image-progress) to render network images. Following the instructions, I also installed [react-native-progress](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-progress).

Here's my component(very similar to the example):

```
<Image
        source={{ uri: 'http://loremflickr.com/640/480/dog' }}
        indicator={ProgressCircle}
        indicatorProps={{
          showsText: true,
        }}
        style={{
          width: 320,
          height: 240,
        }}
 />
```

The indicator - circle appears normally, but circle just spins randomly, no signal of any progress and no text showed as well. After a while, the picture is rendered.

I also tried adding `indeterminate: false` into `indicatorProps`. This time it shows text but is locked at 0%; then after a while picture is rendered.

What possibly have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Problems is missing props : `progress`.

We need to create state and animate like ref : [RN-Progress Example](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-progress/blob/master/Example/app.js)

In the field `indicator`, we need to call function which return `<Progress.Circle>`

```
render() {
    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
        source={{ uri: 'http://loremflickr.com/640/480/dog' }}
        indicator={() => <Progress.Circle
            style={styles.progress}
            progress={this.state.progress}
            indeterminate={this.state.indeterminate}
        />}
        indicatorProps={{
          showsText: true,
        }}
        style={{
          width: 320,
          height: 240,
        }}
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

I try and it's work, hope my answer can help you.

Comment: Sorry for late reply! But how to detect the real progress? In the example the progress was just set random.

Comment: And, the component still doesn't show text. If I put the text inside indicator component it shows, but the value is not accordant to progress.